# Topology textbook for learning discrete mathematics

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

I've been searching for a textbook on point-set topology. I feel that I need the subject somehow as a language, since I often find links on it in textbooks on graphs, models, or formal languages. But the problem is I have very bad feeling of the continuity, or continuous shapes or sets. For example, I understand the algebraic or set-theoretic definition of $\mathbb{R}$, but I do not "accept" the idea of real line. (It's rather difficult for me to imagine the continuity, knowing the universe consists of atoms that are mostly empty.) I've analyzed the situation and come to the conclusion that Kelley's book is good for me. But I'm not sure. Can it really be useful, and is there a book you can recommend (if it's real to study the subject with such "bugs")? P.S. I'm rather good with cumbersome texts with formal proofs.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say "the universe consists of atoms that are mostly empty". If you do read Kelley's book, you will find that it is extremely rigorous. Why not read it and then if you still think there are "bugs" ask a mathematical question about those bugs? (As things stand, your question reads as if you were seeking advice on some kind of religious topic.)

Comment: @RobArthan thanks, I'll try anyway, just want to know beforehand, if it's too difficult, and what are the alternatives.

Comment: Even the physicists who measure the real number valued energy levels of the electrons in mostly space fill atoms, and the chemists who measure the real number valued bonding energies of bunches of those atoms forming a molecule, and others like them, find real numbers convenient, at least, as a **model** for the measurements that they make and for the mathematical theories that they build to incorporate those measurements.

Comment: *"but I do not "accept" the idea of real line"* - in that case you won't make it far in mathematicas, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also find discrete math more intuitive in some sense, as opposed to calculus and analysis.

I would recommend **"Topology" by James r. Munkres**, very well written and helped me understand some of those concepts.

Remark: it is not a discrete math book.